Consistency upper bounds for $\neg\square_{\aleph_\omega}$
In the introduction of Cummings and Friedman's  $\square$ on the singular cardinals the following is written:

Failure of $\square_\lambda$ for $\lambda$ singular is stronger and rather more mysterious;
an unpublished forcing construction of Zeman gives a measurable subcompact cardinal as an upper bound, while at the lower end Steel
has shown that if $\kappa$ is a singular strong limit cardinal and $\square_\kappa$ fails then $\mathsf{AD}^{L(\mathbb{R})}$ holds.

The paper is from 2008, I was wondering whether something more is known by now.
More precisely, I am interested in the upper bound of $\neg\square_{\aleph_\omega}$. Is Zeman's argument available now? Have other upper bounds been found in the midtime?
Thanks

It looks like Zeman’s result is here: https://www.math.uci.edu/~mzeman/RESEARCH/ffs-0-120719.pdf
